# Scheduled Posts and wp-cron - Why don't scheduled posts publish if too old?

Tags: publish, cron, wp-cron, scheduled-posts

I notice that the documentation for `wp_schedule_single_event` mentions the following:-

> The action will fire off when someone visits your WordPress site, if the schedule time has passed.

However this does not seem to be true for scheduled posts. I notice that some posts can be missed if wp-cron is not run for a while (not sure of exact timeframe). The post then has the label 'Missed Schedule' in the admin panel.

My questions are:-

Is this just for scheduled posts or all scheduled events?

What is the timeframe in which wp-cron must be run before scheduled post are missed?

Where is this timeframe set in the code? I cannot seem to find it in wp-cron.php, cron.php or post.php.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure the exact answer but I have a theory that it is a 24 hour window. You can get around relying on `wp-cron` and someone visiting your site every day by having your server handle your cron. Assuming you have cpanel, [it's fairly easy to do](http://support.hostgator.com/articles/specialized-help/technical/wordpress/how-to-replace-wordpress-cron-with-a-real-cron-job).

Then just have this run every 12 or 24 hours. By disabling wp-cron, you also reduce a little load on your server, as otherwise, `wp-cron` will ask if it has jobs to do, every single time a page is loaded.